# remove http headers from response using java/camel

Tags: java, security, http-headers, apache-camel

I need to remove the below headers from response that I sent to 3rd party.

```
$WSIS: 
    $WSPR: HTTP/1.1
    $WSRA: 
    $WSRH: 
    $WSSC: http
    $WSSN: 
    $WSSP: 
    Authorization:
```

What would be the best way to remove the HTTP headers from the response in Java or camel? We are using WAS 8.5 server.

Comment: Which library do you use for HTTP? CXF? Jetty?

Comment: We are using CXF for http.

Answer (score 2):

There isa removeHeaders / removeHeader you can use. The former takes a pattern where you can remove using a wildcard pattern, eg `removeHeader("$W*")`

Comment: We tried with removeHeader option, its not working. What we are not sure is are the above headers added by camel or something else? Because using removeHeaders we can remove camel header.

Comment: These headers are NOT from Camel. You can use Camel tracer to see the message body/headers while Camel routes messages.

Comment: If these are NOT from Camel, then what is the best way to exclude them? using camel or no camel

Comment: You question is too vague/unclear. We cannot help you with so little detail. Do more work yourself first and learn the technologies a bit more

Answer (score 0):

These headers are added by the WebSphere Plugin and not by Camel. Using removeHeader seems to be the only solution. The same worked for me...surely a good workaround but definitely not a solution..